# Bold monospace font extra-large

Tags: fontsize, verbatim, bold, typewriter

I would like to print very large (e.g., font size 43) monospaced bold text. The methods I know don't seem to go together:

```
\documentclass[10pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{anyfontsize}
\font\btt=rm-lmtk10

\begin{document}

{\btt TEXT1}

{\fontsize{43}{48}\selectfont TEXT2}

{\fontsize{43}{48}\selectfont \btt TEXT3}    %not working

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use another font, eg:

```
\documentclass[10pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{bera}
\begin{document}

{\ttfamily TEXT1}

{\fontsize{43}{48}\selectfont TEXT2}

{\fontsize{43}{48}\selectfont \ttfamily TEXT3} 

\end{document}
```

if you prefer the Latin Modern then use instead

```
\documentclass[10pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\begin{document}
...
```

Comment: Thanks! I like the `rm-lmtk` font better. If there's no other way, `\ttfamily` would be ok. Scaling a font up in my mind seems like such a simple task...

Comment: see my edit. You can simply load the lm fonts with the package `lmodern`

Comment: @FrankSeifert - the font `rm-lmtk10` is in the typewriter font for the Lating Modern font family. If you load the `lmodern` package, you'll get `rm-lmtk10` when specifying `\ttfamily`.

Comment: Perfect, much appreciated.

Answer (score 6):

The `\font` instruction should never be used with LaTeX. One of the reasons is what you discovered: the `\btt` font you defined *cannot* be scaled with instructions such as `\fontsize{43}{48}\selectfont`, because it is at a fixed size.

When one issues a font selection command, LaTeX looks in its internal tables and decides what font to use (remembering those it has already looked up and defined), finally issuing a `\font<command>=<tfm-file>` assignment, if needed, and the command `<command>` (for instance, `\OT1/cmr/m/n/10` for the standard font). However this happens deep in the internals and the user should never rely on explicit font selection commands.

The `rm-lmtk10` font is what `lmodern` chooses (scaling it if necessary) when the user requests for

> OT1 encoding, `lmtt` family (Latin Modern Typewriter), bold series, upright shape

as one can read from the entry in the `ot1lmtt.fd` file:

```
\DeclareFontShape{OT1}{lmtt}{b}{n}
     {<-> rm-lmtk10}{}
```

Therefore you can simply use the already defined infrastructure and say

```
\fontsize{43}{48}\usefont{OT1}{lmtt}{b}{n}
```

maybe defining a personal command such as

```
\newcommand{\btt}{\fontsize{43}{48}\usefont{OT1}{lmtt}{b}{n}}
```

Note that `\usefont` issues internally `\selectfont` so it's not needed after `\fontsize`.

Loading `lmodern` is better, but it's not required.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\fontsize{43}{48}\usefont{OT1}{lmtt}{b}{n}
\noindent
TEXT\\
\fontname\font % print the name of the current external font
\end{document}
```

[image]

Note: I used `\font`, but just for accessing the name of the current font, not for defining a new one.

Comment: Outstanding answer. And a great reference for me to start learning Latex fonts.